# Is "turned off by" an appropriate phrase to use in a professional environment?

Tags: meaning-in-context

For example, if I said "Once I saw the details of the contract, I was a bit turned off by the idea." Can this phrase be used professionally, although its common usage is somewhat sexual in nature?

It seems the inverse is almost certainly not professional - "I was really turned on by the prospect of working with that software."

Comment: Any research done?

Comment: It probably depends on the profession (and I don't just mean the oldest profession, but generally based on formality and location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard that phrase used in the professional offices of a Fortune 500 company, in the presence of managers, and no one took exception to it. I have also heard people referring to "sexy features" of particular software, and no one thought it meant anything salacious. I think those metaphors, although they once had  sexual implications, no longer do in a context like that described in the question.

"Turn on" might be more debatable.

Comment: I heard, via a friend, about a (male) finance director saying 'I have a hard-on for this plan!' at a meeting, and shortly after being required to resign.

Comment: @Ronald Sole
Thank you. Fixed